# Showing number isn't constructible

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry

How can I show $\cos \left(\dfrac {2\pi}{7} \right)$ isn't constructible? I'm not sure where to begin. I was thinking of using the fact that $\cos \left(\dfrac {2\pi}{7} \right)+i\sin\left(\dfrac {2\pi}{7} \right)$ is a root of $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$. Thanks for any help

Comment: Try showing that $2\cos \frac{2\pi}{7}$ is a root of $x^3+x^2-2x-1$.

Comment: @vadim123 It might be enlightening to note that is $\xi+\xi^{-1}$ for an obvious $\xi$.